# Array Formula into Regular one

Tags: excel

[image]

Hi everyone, by using an array formulas to calculate (in the above example):

Count unique customers that had purchased only less than 5 units of only product 1 which area code match only with the adjacent D cells

I Use the following array formula to be in E11:

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF($G$2:$G$7=D11,   
   IF($I$2:$I$7="Product 1",IF($J$2:$J$7<5,IF($E$2:$E$7<>"",   
   MATCH($E$2:$E$7,$E$2:$E$7,0))))),ROW($E$2:$E$7)-ROW(G2)+1),1))
```

this formula doing great, at the same time when using it thru very huge database containing tons of rows and columns, excel takes a bout 3 minutes to calculate only one cell which is terrible to continue like that

is there any way to convert this array formula to regular one ... any help will be appreciated to the maximum ... Thanks in advance

Comment: vba will be your best bet.  My guess, without going into it too much, you will not be able to get away from array formulas.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your hint, at the same time i do not mind to use VBA but i dont know to convert such formula into VBA code :) .... I will do anything to avoid all these wasted hours waiting for excel to calculate such formulas :)

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a "Code for me","Teach me to code", or "Find me code" site.

Comment: I do not ask for code, i ask for the logic behind ... anyway .. thanks

Comment: The logic, load the range into an array.  Cycle through each of the 1st dimension of the array testing whether the criteria is met, use a dictionary to ensure that only unique values are counted then return the count of dictionary entries.

Comment: Not sure I understand it correctly, but can't this be done with pivot table?

Comment: There should be a better example. E.g. what is in D11? And what does adjacent D cells mean?

Comment: I do not think so, pivot table will make essential calculations like sum., Average, .... etc. count unique values with multiple criteria will be done only through array formulas ... I'am trying VBA now but I did not get any results yet ... hopefully some one will help by finding a way to replace array formula into regular one

Comment: @MichaelWestwort,in cells (E11:E16) I want to Count Unique customers that meet the following criteria : buy only less than 5 product, buy only product 1 and their area code match with codes in (D11:D16), is that clear ?

Comment: @pnuts, it's just an example

Comment: @RBarryYoung, there is a screenshot to my spreadsheet on the top of page called (Excel sheet screenshot), you could open it to see the whole spreadsheet

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/AwyuR.jpg

Comment: How big are the sheets that are taking 3 minutes?  Meaning how many customers and how many area codes?

Comment: @RBarryYoung, 1000 unique customers repeated over 9500 rows, 350 unique codes repeated over 9500 rows& 8 unique products repeated over 9500 rows .... and this array formula is written in a table of 350 rows (row per unique code)

Comment: As @pnuts already asked: why is E11 1? this area has only customer4 which got product1 7 times... this way, it should be 0... or am I wrong? Also, if a customer got 5+ in sum within one area, count him? if yes, how about the sum with other areas? also count it if the sum is 5+? Right now it looks like: "Count up for each different 'customer' in specified 'area' which got at least one time less than 5 items of 'product1' " so if product 1 and 2 is purchased, still count him. and if just the sum is 5+, still count him... to me it is not completely clear when to count and when not :/

Comment: @DirkReichel, Sorry if it was unclear .. I will explain in details here if u do not mind .... First, E11 is just the first cell corresponding to the first code, I will drag it later to automate other cells below. Second, Customer 4 had purchased Product1 7 times, so it should be Zero as u previously illustrated, thanks for that, it was just an extra wrong comma in my equation which led to that fault.

Comment: @DirkReichel, Third, If any customer got +5 in sum within any area, It should not be count. Fourth, For my data there is no customer that exist two times in two different areas, its impossible. Here another screenshot, hope it will work ... thanks a lot for your hints

Comment: @DirkReichel, I edited screenshot, http://i.stack.imgur.com/ny1bY.jpg

Comment: Maybe I should go to sleep... I still don't get it... Just as an example for me (not related to your picture): In Area1 is customer 1 and 2. so we now check the sum of all "product 1 purcase" from cosumer 1 and 2 (seperately) while the area doesn't matter for the sum. Lets say it is 3 and 4. The outcome would be 2. but if cusomer 2 also hat purcased product 2 somewhere, would this change anything?

Comment: No Mr. @DirkReichel, I updated my screenshot and post also an url to to the new one in a previous comment

Comment: No, it will not change anything .... only product1 which is matter

Comment: OK thanks for the clarification... I'll run some tests now ;)

Comment: Anyway thanks a lot for your appreciated hints and try :)

Comment: You example says that area 173A2 has only one unique customer that meets the criteria.  However, my visual inspection seems to say that it should be 2 (Customer 1 and Customer 2), and when I copy your spreadsheet and formula I get 2 for that area code.  Which is correct and why?

Comment: @RBarryYoung 2 is correct for 173A2 and 1 for 169A2 (other should be 0)... the error is due an aditional comma inside the formula... this way the picture is not correct ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the late answer.

I created an UDF which is focused on doing the calculation several times without running the whole range multiple times.

```
Public Function getCounts(AreaStr As Variant, AreaRng As Range, CustomerRng As Range, ProductRng As Range, SalesRng As Range, Optional ProductName As String = "Product 1", Optional lessThan As Double = 5) As Variant

  'make sure AreaStr is an array
  If TypeOf AreaStr Is Range Then AreaStr = AreaStr.Value2
  If Not IsArray(AreaStr) Then
    AreaStr = Array(AreaStr)
    ReDim Preserve AreaStr(1 To 1)
  End If

  'shorten the range (this way you can use whole columns)
  If SalesRng(SalesRng.Cells.Count).Formula = "" Then Set SalesRng = SalesRng.Parent.Range(SalesRng.Cells(1), SalesRng(SalesRng.Cells.Count).End(xlUp))

  'make sure all ranges have the same size
  Set AreaRng = AreaRng.Resize(SalesRng.Rows.Count)
  Set CustomerRng = CustomerRng.Resize(SalesRng.Rows.Count)
  Set ProductRng = ProductRng.Resize(SalesRng.Rows.Count)

  'Load values in variables to increase speed
  Dim SalesValues As Variant, UserValues As Variant, ProductValues As Variant
  SalesValues = AreaRng
  UserValues = CustomerRng
  ProductValues = ProductRng

  'create temporary arrays to hold the values
  Dim buffer() As Variant, expList() As Variant
  ReDim buffer(1 To UBound(UserValues))
  ReDim expList(1 To UBound(AreaStr), 1 To 1)

  Dim i As Long, j As Double, k As Long
  For i = 1 To UBound(AreaStr)
    expList(i, 1) = buffer
  Next

  buffer = Array(buffer, buffer)
  buffer(0)(1) = 0

  For i = 1 To UBound(UserValues)
    If ProductValues(i, 1) = ProductName Then 'this customer purchased our product
      j = Application.IfError(Application.Match(UserValues(i, 1), buffer(0), 0), 0)
      If j = 0 Then 'first time this customer in this calculation
        j = i
        buffer(0)(j) = UserValues(i, 1) 'remember the customer name (to not calculate him again later)
        If Application.SumIfs(SalesRng, CustomerRng, UserValues(i, 1), ProductRng, ProductName) < lessThan Then
          buffer(1)(j) = 1 'customer got less than "lessThan" -> remember that
        End If
      End If
      If buffer(1)(j) = 1 Then 'check if we need to count the customer
        k = Application.IfError(Application.Match(SalesValues(i, 1), AreaStr, 0), 0) 'check if the area is one of the areas we are looking for
        If k Then expList(k, 1)(j) = 1 'it is -> set 1 for this customer/area combo
      End If
    End If
  Next

  For i = 1 To UBound(AreaStr) 'sum each area
    expList(i, 1) = Application.Sum(expList(i, 1))
  Next

  getCounts = expList 'output array

End Function
```

I assume that you will be able to include it as an UDF without my help.

In the sheet you would use (for your example) E11:E16

```
=getCounts(D11:D15,G2:G7,E2:E7,I2:I7,J2:J7)
```

simply select the range of E11:E16 and enter the formula, then confirm it with CSE.

you also could use only `=getCounts(D11,$G$2:$G$7,$E$2:$E$7,$I$2:$I$7,$J$2:$J$7)` at E11 and then copy down... but that would be pretty slow.

The trick is, that we calculate the sum of the set for every customer, which at least bought it one time. Then we store 1 if it is less then your criteria. This goes for the general array. Every area you are looking for, will get its own array too. Here we also store the 1 at the same pos. As every costomer only gets calculated one time, having him multiple times doesn't matter.

the formula simply will be used like this:

```
getCounts(AreaStr,AreaRng,CustomerRng,ProductRng,SalesRng,[ProductName],[lessThan])
```

- AreaStr: the area code you are looking for. should be an array of multiple cells to make the udf worth using it
- AreaRng: the range where the area names are stored
- CustomerRng: the range where the customer names are stored
- ProductRng: the range where the product names are stored
- SalesRng: the range where the sale counts are stored
- ProductName (optional): the product you are looking for. Will be "Product 1" if omited
- lessThan (optional): the trigger point for the sum of products. Will be 5 if omited

Most parts should be self explaining, but if you still have any questions, just ask ;)

Comment: Dear Dirk, it works perfectly, thanks a lot for your cooperative spirit, sorry for my late feedback, but I was trying hardly to understand each part of it before applying it, it works for the previous example perfectly, at the same time, if I want to make changes to my data ranges such as array length or column name (e.g, Product into Brand Name, or Area Code to Area ID), this will change any thing in my UDF or not, if yes which parts that I will change when changing my columns headers names or result cells? ..... Appreciated to the MAX. Thanks+++++  :)

Comment: It's OK, I did it and change what is need to be changed, now I want to make another column count the same conditions but count customers purchased more than 5, how to make the first UDF works for specific range and another UDF to work for different range in the same sheet?, thats the challenge now :)

Comment: For doing the opposite you would need to do some adjustments... I will look into that if I am at home again...

Answer (score 0):

OK, I am not sure of I understood all of the conditions and accumulation, but here is a VBA function that I think should do it.

First, open VBA from the Excel Developer menu.  Then in VBA, create a new module from the Insert menu (just let it be Module1).  Then paste the following 2 functions into the VBA module.

```
Public Function AreaUniqueCustomersLessThan(ReportAreaRange, AreaRange, ProductRange, SalesRange, CustomerRange)
  On Error GoTo Err1
    Dim RptAreas() As Variant
    Dim Areas() As Variant, Products() As Variant, Sales() As Variant, Customers As Variant

    RptAreas = ArrayFromRange(ReportAreaRange)

    Areas = ArrayFromRange(AreaRange)
    Products = ArrayFromRange(ProductRange)
    Sales = ArrayFromRange(SalesRange)
    Customers = ArrayFromRange(CustomerRange)

    Dim r As Long, s As Long    'report and source rows indexes
    Dim mxr As Long, mxs As Long
    mxr = UBound(RptAreas, 1)
    mxs = UBound(Areas, 1)


    'encode the ReportAreasList into accumulation array indexes
    Dim AreaCustomers() As Collection
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim colAreas As New Collection

    ReDim AreaCustomers(1 To mxr)
    For r = 1 To mxr
        On Error Resume Next
            'Do we have the area already?
            j = colAreas(RptAreas(r, 1))
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            'Add a new area to the collection and array
            i = i + 1
            colAreas.Add i, RptAreas(r, 1)
            Set AreaCustomers(i) = New Collection
            j = i
        End If
    Next r

    'now scan the source rows, accumulating distinct customers
    ' for any ReportAreas
    For s = 1 To mxs
        'is this row's Arera in the report Area list?
        i = 0
        On Error Resume Next
            i = colAreas(Areas(s, 1))
        On Error GoTo Err1
        If i > 0 Then

            'this is a report Area code, so check the conditions
            If Products(s, 1) = "Product 1" Then
                If Sales(s, 1) < 5 Then

                    On Error Resume Next    'just ignore any duplicate errors
                        AreaCustomers(i).Add Customers(s, 1), Customers(s, 1)
                    On Error GoTo Err1

                End If
            End If

        End If
    Next s

    'finally, return to the report area codes, returning the distinct count
    ' of customers
    Dim count() As Variant
    ReDim count(1 To mxr, 1 To 1)
    For r = 1 To mxr
        count(r, 1) = AreaCustomers(colAreas(RptAreas(r, 1))).count
    Next r

    AreaUniqueCustomersLessThan = count  ' "foo"
    Exit Function

Err1:
    AreaUniqueCustomersLessThan = "%ERR(" & Str(Err.Number) & ")%" & Err.Description
    Exit Function
    Resume

End Function


'handle all of the cases, checking and conversions to convert
' a variant range into an array of Variant(1 to n, 1 to 1)
' (we do this because it makes data access very fast)
Function ArrayFromRange(varRange As Variant)
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim A() As Variant

    Set rng = varRange

    'Check for degenerate cases
    If rng Is Nothing Then
        'do nothing
    ElseIf rng.count = 0 Then
        'do nothing

    ElseIf rng.count = 1 Then
        ReDim A(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
        A(1, 1) = rng.Value

    Else
        A = rng.Value
    End If

    ArrayFromRange = A
End Function
```

Finally, go to your Array Formula area and paste in the following Array formula for the "Sales < 5" list:  `{=AreaUniqueCustomersLessThan(D$11:D$16, G$2:G$7, I$2:I$7,J$2:J$7,E$2:E$7)}`  Note that the first range must be the same length as the Array Formula range itself.  And the other four ranges (the source data ranges) should all be the same length (they do not have to be the same length as the first range).